# Build a source using <regex.h> with i586-mingw32msvc-gcc

Tags: regex, mingw, cross-compiling

I try to compile a source file which include the `<regex.h>` with `i586-mingw32msvc-gcc`:

```
$ i586-mingw32msvc-gcc parser.c -Ilibregex/include -o parser.o
```

And I get this:

```
/tmp/ccPpDhjW.o:parser.c:(.text+0xfd): undefined reference to `__imp__regcomp'
/tmp/ccPpDhjW.o:parser.c:(.text+0x144): undefined reference to `__imp__regexec'
/tmp/ccPpDhjW.o:parser.c:(.text+0x158): undefined reference to `__imp__regfree'
/tmp/ccPpDhjW.o:parser.c:(.text+0x18f): undefined reference to `__imp__regcomp'
/tmp/ccPpDhjW.o:parser.c:(.text+0x1b8): undefined reference to `__imp__regerror'
/tmp/ccPpDhjW.o:parser.c:(.text+0x1fc): undefined reference to `__imp__regexec'
/usr/lib/gcc/i586-mingw32msvc/4.2.1-sjlj/../../../../i586-mingw32msvc/lib/libmingw32.a(main.o):(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `_WinMain@16'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My folder `libregex/include` contains the `regex.h`.

Has anyone tried to compile a source containing `<regex.h>` with `mingw` in cross compilation?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `#define PCRE_STATIC` before including `pcreposix.h`.

Comment: Then, instead of the error `undefined reference to _imp__regcomp`, I get the error `undefined reference to regcomp`

Answer (score 0):

add `-lregex` 
which works fine with [msys2](https://www.msys2.org/) w64-x86_64